# How Do I Output Regression Result Tables to Word from Knitr / R RStudio? (mtable, memisc)

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to output regression result tables to Word from knitr but I'm having trouble. Outputting *mtable*s to \LaTeX works if I tweak the options but I'm stuck when it comes to Word. My MWE is below.

````
---
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(memisc)
```

## This section contains ugly text, not a table
```{r eval = T, include = T, echo = F}
lm0 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75,              data = LifeCycleSavings)
lm1 <- lm(sr ~                 dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
lm2 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

mt01 <- mtable(lm0,lm1,summary.stats=c("R-squared","N"))
mt12 <- mtable(lm1,lm2,summary.stats=c("R-squared","F","N"))

c("Group 1"=mt01,
"Group 2"=mt12)
```
````

Comment: I'm puzzled. The help page for `memisc::mtable` uses code almost identical to this and it has a section on making output suitable for MS Word. There's also support for html (which should be readable my MSW as well): http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/memisc/html/mtable-format-html.html

Comment: Could you be more specific? Or, if it is easy for you, could you provide an example? I was aware that one could create an HTML table which could then be imported as a MS Word or LibreOffice as described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/vignettes/mtable-html.html) and I've read the help files. Unfortunately, I cannot manage to render an memisc::mtable into Word as I can other tools, such as kable.

Comment: Hi RTS, I've tried, the help page says "The contents of this file can be pasted into Word and converted into a Word table.". I've tried and couldn't get it straight. The answer is not that easy it seems.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look as well. I suppose the answer will involve tweaking knitr options. For now however, it's intractable.

Answer (score 0):

I've devised an ugly hack that works. I hope it can help someone else in my position. I am fairly certain that an obvious and simpler way to achieve this exists.

````
---
output:
  word_document: default
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(memisc)
```

## This section contains a table, not ugly text
```{r eval = T, include = T, echo = F}
lm0 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75,              data = LifeCycleSavings)
lm1 <- lm(sr ~                 dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
lm2 <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)

mt01 <- mtable(lm0,lm1,summary.stats=c("R-squared","N"))
mt12 <- mtable(lm1,lm2,summary.stats=c("R-squared","F","N"))

x = c("Group 1"=mt01,"Group 2"=mt12)

x = memisc::mtable_format_delim(x)
writeLines(x,"table.csv")
x = read.delim("table.csv", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(x) = x[1,]
x = x[-1,]
rownames(x) = NULL
knitr::kable(x)
```
````